# warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous when using git-svn

Tags: git, branch, git-svn, ambiguity

I am using git as a frontend to Subversion (via git svn).

So, for every svn trunk/branch I have remote branch in git named "remotes/xxx". For example "remotes/trunk", "remotes/coolfeature".

Now I want have one "default" local branch for every remote branch, to use it for dcommit. The problem is that I want such branches to be named after Subversion branches, like "trunk", "coolfeature", so I have the following branches in git:

```
trunk
coolfeature
remotes/trunk
remotes/coolfeature
```

The problem is that every time I reference "trunk" or "coolfeature" git complains branch name is ambiguous. Not a big deal, but I feel uncomfortable.

The question is, how can I deal with that warning, assuming that simply renaming branches is not what I want to do. What are the best practices for such cases?

Comment: I'm not sure. I avoided this by just choosing different but similar names. However, you could try using `refs/heads/trunk` or maybe even just `heads/trunk`. I think that should work.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046698/git-refname-origin-master-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you pass the `--prefix=svn/` flag to the `git svn clone` command, then all of the Subversion branches would be named like `remotes/svn/branchname`. If this is acceptable to you, it fixes the "refname is ambiguous" warning. It also gives you a nice way of referring to the remote svn branches, as in for instance if you want to create a local tracking branch it would be something like:

`$ git checkout -b branchname svn/branchname`

The local branch then has the same name as the remote svn branch, and no ambiguous refname problem.

Comment: How can I fix a repository I already cloned to have `--prefix=svn/`?

Comment: I just cloned into a new directory and then fetched the local branches I had from the other directory: git fetch ../other_dir branch_name:branch_name  --- tab completion is great for the branch names too.

Comment: If you have already created a branch with the same name, you can rename your branch with this command: git branch -m [currentName] [newName]

Comment: As of git 2 the svn prefex is set by default to svn/ if you want a different prefix or want to track multiple svn repo's make sure you set it during the clone OR via .git/config

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to get rid of warning, set `core.warnAmbiguousRefs` to `false`:

```
git config --global core.warnambiguousrefs false
```

If you want this behavior only for single repository, omit `--global` flag.

Comment: I probably violated all all known/unknown rules here, but I tried "git tag -a HEAD -m 'Start of repo'" on a new repo, after which I received the OPs error message. The fix described in this post allowed me to keep working.

Answer (score 1):

It can be possible that you have another 'trunk' and 'coolfeature' as a tag. In this case, git doesn't know if you refer to branch or tag. Rename the tags and check if git doesn't report "ambiguous" name

Comment: This is not the case for me. `.git/refs/` contains unambiguous names. I don't have any tags. What is causing git to complain in first place?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the conflict messages, when referring to local branches, prefix them with `heads/`

for example, the conflicting branch `topic`

```
$ git diff topic remotes/topic
warning: reframe 'topic' is ambiguous.
...
```

becomes

```
$ git diff heads/topic remotes/topic
...
```