# Git flow release branches and tags - with or without "v" prefix

Tags: git, naming-conventions, git-flow

I have seen multiple contradicting definitions on various git flow related websites. Is there an official recommendation or single source of truth?

Branches: `release-1.2.3` or `release-v1.2.3`

Tags: `1.2.3` or `v1.2.3`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006265/is-there-a-standard-naming-convention-for-git-tags

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Well, basically it is a matter of preference, but I prefer the version with the `v`, as [Semver](http://semver.org/) does it [that way](https://github.com/semver/semver/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and I try to follow that specification as close as possible to get a sane versioning.

It also makes filtering for those Tags easier, as you can press `v` and then the <kbd>TAB</kbd>-key for autocompletion: This will list all the tags (and maybe a few branches), whereas there are several digits a tag could start with.

Edit: In 2019, Semver added a section to their FAQ, clarifying that the "v" prefix is "a common way to indicate a version number" (see ["Is “v1.2.3” a semantic version?"](https://semver.org/#is-v123-a-semantic-version)).

---

See also: [Is there a standard naming convention for git tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006265/is-there-an-standard-naming-convention-for-git-tags)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I think it is interesting to see that the Git Flow project itself does **not** use the v prefixes: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow
For the reasons you and @VonC posted, I still prefer version tags that include the v prefix.

Comment: Semver has removed the prefixed *v* in version 2.

Comment: See: https://github.com/mojombo/semver/blob/master/semver.md#user-content-is-v123-a-semantic-version

Comment: @schmijos @LeoTM - The document only states that v1.2.3 is not a semantic version. The question was about Git tags. In fact, the semver repo still uses `v2.0.0` as a tag for version 2: https://github.com/mojombo/semver/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Comment: semver 2.0 http://semver.org doesn't state anything about the tags needed to begin with a "v" prefix!

Comment: You say Semver does it with the v, but your link to the SemVer definition makes no mention of 'v', and shows many examples without it.

Comment: Since there's some debate on what Semver 2.0 says, let me quote it: '“v1.2.3” is not a semantic version. However, prefixing a semantic version with a “v” is a common way (in English) to indicate it is a version number. Abbreviating “version” as “v” is often seen with version control. Example: git tag v1.2.3 -m "Release version 1.2.3"'

Comment: The quoted part by @JakeStevens-Haas means that SemVer no longer "does it that way" as the answer stated, so the answer is claiming something that is no longer true.

Answer (score 40):

Since v stands for version, tags are generally named vX.Y.Z, with X.Y.Z following [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/).

This allows for branches X.Y.Z to co-exist with those tags, without having to deal with error message like "fatal: Ambiguous object name" (as in "[Ambiguous Names with GIT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307956/ambiguous-names-with-git)").

Note that the tags for Git itself have recently been "adapted" for a surprising reason: see "[Code version change “rules”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377717/6309)".

Comment: When people are using best practice like _semver_, then they probably use a system like _Git Flow_ or something similar. That would prevent that clash of refs (branch eq tag name). Aside from that, what would hold one back from naming a branch `vX.Y.Z` then? That's not really that much of an argument :)

Comment: semver 2.0 http://semver.org doesn't state anything about the tags needed to begin with a "v" prefix!

Comment: @jankal I agree. I only mentioned semver for the X.Y.Z policy.

Comment: One minor argument is that more people will get `v1.2.3` than `b1.2.3` :-)

Answer (score 10):

https://semver.org/#is-v123-a-semantic-version

> **Is “v1.2.3” a semantic version?** No, “v1.2.3” is not a semantic
>   version. However, prefixing a semantic version with a “v” is a common
>   way (in English) to indicate it is a version number. Abbreviating
>   “version” as “v” is often seen with version control. Example: git tag
>   v1.2.3 -m "Release version 1.2.3", in which case “v1.2.3” is a tag
>   name and the semantic version is “1.2.3”.