# Why GitHub suggest "prefix your version names with the letter v?"

Tags: git, github

This is the content at GitHub's right sidebar:

> Tagging suggestions It’s common practice to prefix your version names
>   with the letter v. Some good tag names might be v1.0 or v2.3.4.
>
> If the tag isn’t meant for production use, add a pre-release version
>   after the version name. Some good pre-release versions might be
>   v0.2-alpha or v5.9-beta.3.
>
> Semantic versioning If you’re new to releasing software, we highly
>   recommend reading about [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/).

I don't understand why **prefix your version names with the letter v**? Please explain for me, why prefix version names with letter **v** is best-practice?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most open source projects, and many tags on github and other open VCS sites, follow a format called [Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/), linked also in the quote in your question.  This is the versioning model that suggests:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version
>      when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH
>      version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional
>   labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions
>   to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

The SEMVER recommendation has gone through a few revisions of its own, and at one point recommended prefacing a tag with a "v", but these days I believe it does not mention the practice. Nevertheless, many sites, projects and conventions have followed this former SEMVER practice, and haven't updated themselves to follow the newer recommendations.

My own opinion is that it probably doesn't matter whether you start your tags with a "v" or not. But you may have an easier time using tools like `sort` if you don't.

Comment: As of writing, if you're working in Go, it matters (prefixing with "v" is **required**). See https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32945

Comment: @gotgenes, wow, lots of opinions there. From my perspective, it is unfortunate that there are such strong voices opposing a "standard" (semver) that is in wide use elsewhere. Go certainly has problems here, but they are not unsolvable. I have only ever used Go in projects which used semver, and Go components were pulled in by git hash. Perhaps this is why. :-/  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ghoti
SemVer does not prescribe usage of `v` as per https://github.com/semver/semver/issues/235#issuecomment-346477428

It only prescribes the version formatting.

`v` is usually used on tags

Comment: @AlexSkrypnyk .. I didn't say it *prescribed* use of a `v`. In fact, that section of the spec describing its use as a tag prefix was [removed in 2011](https://github.com/semver/semver/commit/52c9b2b3a6603042b2591bd6c52dc7c3ee662684) as it was a distraction. An explanation of its use was [added back to the FAQ in 2015](https://github.com/semver/semver/commit/ba78eedf7755745ea519382ea7327ba87b57087b).

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason, you can easily filter on tags that start with 'v' (as you may have other tags to track commits other than releases). From the answers to this similar question:
[Git flow release branches and tags - with or without "v" prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639437/git-flow-release-branches-and-tags-with-or-without-v-prefix/21639868)