# Error when creating branch in git

Tags: git, msysgit

I am using git-svn repo on Windows, using msysgit 1.8.5. Here is my `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"] 
    url = https://svn.domain.com:8443/svn
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = branches/{BR_4_1_4}:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

And my list of branches:

```
$ git branch -a
  BR_4_1_4
* trunk
  remotes/branches/BR_4_1_4
  remotes/trunk
```

And I want to create a branch off of `trunk` named `trunk_work`, so I issue the following command (you can also see the subsequent error):

```
$ git branch trunk_work
warning: refname 'trunk' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'trunk'.
```

Any idea why this is failing? I Googled a bit but didn't see anything specific to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225704/703229

Comment: @SamSullivan I'm not creating a tag, I'm trying to create a branch with a completely different name. Not sure what you expected me to find...

Comment: Potentially helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644380/git-warning-refname-xxx-is-ambiguous (the second highest rates answer might at least give a workaround).

Comment: @Chris Perfect! If you post an answer I'll give you a green checkmark! Thanks!

Comment: Will do, although not technically my answer =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned in the comments, I think you can probably solve your problem using the solutions given in this answer: [Git: warning: refname 'xxx' is ambiguous when using git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644380/git-warning-refname-xxx-is-ambiguous)

I think the second highest rated answer may be the one you're most interested in:

```
git config --global core.warnambiguousrefs false
```

Although it also looked like, from those comments, that specifiying the branch in the format `heads/trunk` (if that's the one you're interested in), may do the job.

Some documentation: [Git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.8.1.5)