# git refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a git repository that is tracking several remote branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/git-svn
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/trunk
```

When I try to setup a default one I get the following error:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/master'.
```

I would like to kremove some of the remote master branches but the master references are still there. How can I remove them to be able to set the default upstream branch to `origin/master`?

```
$ git show-ref master
cba97a58c99743c355b569bbf35636c8823c2d96 refs/heads/master
6726b4985107e2ddc7539f95e1a6aba536d35bc6 refs/origin/master
d83f025cd3800ed7acd76b2e52ae296e33f1cd07 refs/original/refs/heads/master
cba97a58c99743c355b569bbf35636c8823c2d96 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Comment: Just to be sure: what does `git branch -l` tell you? What about `git tag`?

Comment: `git branch -l` gives me `master`. There are no tags in the repository.

Comment: Try `git branch --set-upstream-to=refs/remotes/origin/master master`.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

The output of `git branch -a` shows that you have a remote-tracking branch called `origin/master`. Perfectly normal.

However, the output of `git show-ref master` contains

```
6726b4985107e2ddc7539f95e1a6aba536d35bc6 refs/origin/master
```

which indicates that you most likely ran something like the following low-level command:

```
git update-ref refs/origin/master master
```

This command creates a branch (pointing at the same commit as `master`) called `origin/master`, but living directly under `refs/`, i.e. *outside* the `refs/heads/` namespace, where local branches normally live. Quite suspicious... Did you mean to do that?

Such a branch won't get listed by `git branch -a`. Git is getting confused, though, because it sees two branches whose refnames end with `origin/master`:

- `refs/remotes/origin/master`, your remote-tracking branch, and
- `refs/origin/master`, the local branch that you created (by accident) outside `refs/heads/`.

### Solution

#### If you did *not* mean to create `refs/origin/master`

Simply delete it:

```
git update-ref -d refs/origin/master
```

Then, there won't be any ambiguity, and Git will comply when you try to set `master`'s upstream.

#### If you did mean to create `refs/origin/master`

To avoid ambiguity, simply specify the *full* refname of the branch you wish to set as `master`'s upstream:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=refs/remotes/origin/master master
```

---

To fix ideas, here is some code that reproduces the situation in one of my GitHub repos:

```
$ cd ~/Desktop
$ git clone https://github.com/Jubobs/gitdags && cd gitdags

$ git update-ref refs/origin/master

$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

$ git show-ref master
15b28ec22dfb072ff4369b35ef18df51bb55e900 refs/heads/master
15b28ec22dfb072ff4369b35ef18df51bb55e900 refs/origin/master
15b28ec22dfb072ff4369b35ef18df51bb55e900 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
15b28ec22dfb072ff4369b35ef18df51bb55e900 refs/remotes/origin/master

$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/master'.

$ git update-ref -d refs/origin/master
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified  `push.default` should be set to `upstream` (as `matching` will be ambiguous)

Comment: thanks. Very well answered by explaining the cause, solution, and replicate the symptom.

Comment: My issue was the same root cause but I must have gotten there a different way. The explanation was clear enough that I was able to adapt it to my situation. Well written explanation. There is a lot of technical writing on SO, some great and some not. This is great technical writing.

Comment: @MatthewPoer Thank you for your nice comment; I appreciate it.

Comment: could this be caused by having multiple similar branch args to git svn clone? (i.e.  -b /branches/* -b branches/*/*)?

Comment: @mike01010 I'm not sure. Maybe. I'd have to test this.

Comment: @jub0bs - can confirm it does cause the issue

Comment: @mike01010 Very interesting! Feel free to add details in my answer or one of your own.

Comment: remove ref does work. But what is the cause? someone commit ambiguous refs to repo?

Answer (score 49):

You probably accidentally created a local ref called 'origin/master'

for instance, if you did this

```
git branch origin/master
```

It would lead to this problem. This one looks suspect "refs/origin/master".  "refs/heads/master" is your local master, "refs/remotes/origin/master" is your remote branch reference, and "refs/origin/master" is probably a mistake that is screwing you up.

You just need to delete that reference (git update-ref -d ) and things will start working again.

Comment: If that were the case, the output of `git branch -a` would contain an entry reading `origin/master`.

Comment: Normally yes, I have seen instances where people have created oddball refs that don't show up in `git branch` output though

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that was the problem.

Comment: That was my issue

Comment: @AndrewC: Good answer, worked for me. But you should add the command to 'delete that reference' in your answer as well.

Answer (score 10):

I faced the same problem few days back where there were multiple references created of the same branch.

Things i tried:

```
> git show-ref (will give you the list of references, from the
> references list you can check if there are multiple references created
> for the branch you are working on or not.)
```

If there are multiple references created then simply remove it

```
rm .git/refs/heads/master
```

After removing the references you can take the checkout of the branch from remote origin only if you have pushed something in it, otherwise you have to redo everything which you did in the branch

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/branchName
```

This solution worked out for me in case of ambiguous branches.

Answer (score 8):

I had a very similar problem due to an accidental tag named "master", showing in `git show-ref master` as `refs/tags/master`.  The fix in this case was:

```
git tag -d master
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `.git` directory itself contains a ref called `master`, i.e. `.git/master`, you will see the same error message. The nasty issue here is that you won't get this ref reported by commands like `git branch -a` nor `git show-ref master`. (git version 2.30.0.windows.2)

Comment: Helped me! This is similar to the accepted answer — a ref file stored outside `.git/refs/heads/` where local branches normally live — except when it's directly at top level outside `refs/`, even `git show-ref` won't list it :-(, and `update-ref -d` will refuse to delete "bad name", need `rm`. But `update-ref foo/bar` [happily creates one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36006054/why-does-git-update-ref-accepts-non-refs-references).  Apparently these are called [pseudoref](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#def_pseudoref) — like .git/FETCH_HEAD etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.git/config` file. You may run into this problem if you have more than one remote repo configured with the same:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

The other remote server should have a different name, eg.:

`fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/another_repo/*`