# git svn clone update_ref failed for ref, refusing to update ref with bad name

Tags: git, svn, migration, repository, git-clone

I'm trying to migrate my SVN repo to a Git repo. During a `git svn clone` command I get the following error

> Unrecognized escape \M passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^([0-9a-fA-F]+)
>
> fatal: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/8.0-R3\MyProject@26482': refusing to update ref with bad name refs/remotes/origin/8.0-R3\MyProject@26482
>   update-ref -m r32123 refs/remotes/origin/8.0-R3\MyProject@26482 a48597b7e7a12f9deed97b07b1685994eae7369b: command returned error: 128

I think the error is caused due to a backslash in the path.
I tried ignoring the path using `--ignore-paths` but it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046698/git-refname-origin-master-is-ambiguous. If you can fix the ref, then maybe you will be able to ignore the file you are suspecting to be the cause of the error.