# How to have my branch display "Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

before I write some command I found on google, git console was saying

> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

when I type in `git status`.

So, after I typed in (`git push -u origin 01-MyfeatureProductListing`) that I found on google, when I check the status (git status), it is now saying :

> Your branch is up to date with 'origin/01-MyfeatureProductListing'.

How do I bring it back to the old way? (Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'), everytime when I type "**git status**"

Using Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the upstream branch of your current branch back to `origin/master`,
use the [`-u|--set-upstream-to`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--ultupstreamgt) option of `git branch` :

```
git branch -u origin/master
```

---

The `-u` flag you passed to `git push` instructed git to link your current branch to remote branch `origin/01-MyfeatureProductListing`. `git branch -u` allows you to override this to any remote branch you want.
You can also use `--unset-upstream` to stop having git compare your local branch with a remote branch.

You can view the links between local branches and remote branches in the `.git/config` file of your local clone ; if you open this file with any text editor (gedit, notepad, vscode ... ), you should see several sections looking like :

```
[branch "mybranch"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/01-MyfeatureProductListing
```

The above means local branch `mybranch` is set up to track `origin/01-MyfeatureProductListing`.
The `-u` option simply updates this section.

---

[edit] *obviously* : the `-u` option to `git push` is completely optional, if you want to push without setting or updating the remote tracked branch, just drop the `-u` option ...

Comment: type `git branch -u origin/master`                                                                                              
 Get `Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.`

Comment: @SarthakRaval : yes, that's the expected behavior. Do you have a question regarding this message ? or is it just a remark to mention the message one should expect ?

Comment: how to check my  `git status`   and reenter  `git branch -u origin/master`  I get  `warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/master'.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046698/git-refname-origin-master-is-ambiguous

Comment: use google to search your error message `fatal: Ambiguous object name`, you will find posts explaining how to spot things (branches, tags, remote branches, references) that may confuse git because they have the same name

Answer (score 3):

`git status` will show whether your current local branch is ahead or behind the remote tracking branch it is associated with.

(To bring the remote tracking branch up to date with a remote's – eg. `origin` – branch use `git fetch`, itself used by `git pull`.)

Because you pushed with the `-u` (aka `--set-upstream`) option a remote tracking branch for `origin/01-MyfeatureProductListing` was created.

If you want to compare your local working branch `01-MyfeatureProductListing` with `origin/master`:

1. `git fetch` to ensure you local repository has any changes made on the remote.
2. `git diff "origin/master..HEAD" to compare your remote tracking branch for`master`with the latest commit on your current branch (almost always aliased to`HEAD`).

There is no direct way to get a `git status` like display between your current local branch and an arbitrary remote tracking branch.

Comment: _There is no direct way to get a git status like display between your current local branch and an arbitrary remote tracking branch_         But it was showing like so before !  I just need it to come back the way it was. (**Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'**)

Comment: @CodingValue As noted by LeGAC you can change the remote tracking branch, but that will mean you will push to `master` which would seem not what you want.