# Git warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous

Tags: git

I got this error.

```
$ git merge origin/master
warning: refname 'origin/master' is ambiguous.
```

I check the refs of `origin/master`, it contains two rather than only remote one:

```
$ git show-ref origin/master
b73e1c8fd21c28926884c8ac61d0666172930fef refs/heads/origin/master (wrong one)
aea283f55e75242cf57134c824e05007df4fab06 refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the adopted answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26047558/873234 delete the wrong refs and it works.

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/heads/origin/master
```

Comment: just delete the repo content from your system and again clone your repo that will solve your issue.